# Monitor a txt file for lack of modification in the last minute and mail me

Tags: windows, file, email, notifications, monitor

I'm looking for the best way to check if a txt file hasn't been modified for the last 10 seconds. It has to check it automatically every minute and if it results in a lack of modification it has to send an email to me.

The server in which the script/software will be used is running on **Windows**.

**DETAILS**

I have a software which edit a txt file every minute to let me know it is still running. If the software fails to edit the txt file it means it doesn't running anymore and I have to be notified as soon as possible, so I need a script/software to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with simple powershell script like that

```
#endless loop
while ($true)
{
#Getting difference between last write time for your TXT, and current system time, converting it to seconds
$diff=((Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\YourTXTfile.log).LastWriteTime - (get-date)).totalseconds
#Check, if it greater than 10 seconds
if ($diff -gt -10) 
{
#you dont need this write-host in your prod, so remove it after testing
Write-Host "Everything is ok. File last modified $diff seconds ago. Next check in 10 seconds"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
else
{
Send-MailMessage -To "some@mail.com" -Body "Seems like our app is down" -SmtpServer "yourSMTP" -Subject "Etc, etc"
#you dont need this write-host in your prod, so remove it after testing
Write-Host "Mail report out, next check will be performed in one hour"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
}
}
```

and put it to task scheduler to run as background task.